# Now that the app is no longer available, what is the recommended method for having your phone beep on SE notifications?

Tags: support, android-app, stack-exchange, notifications, audio

Up to a few days ago, I was able to keep up to date with the notifications from Stack Exchange, using the official Stack Exchange app. Every time a notification was issued, my phone would beep and then I could see what happened.

Now that I changed the ROM on my phone though, the Stack Exchange app seems to not be available at the play store any more.

So the question is this: given that SE app is no longer available, what is the recommended method for maintaining your addiction to SE, by receiving a notification on your phone for all SE notifications?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Is there a well known solution for this?

Comment: Some of the links in the answers [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47750/stack-overflow-desktop-notifier) might still be relevant.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask: That's interesting, but the answers seem to be for desktop, not for mobile.

Comment: You could probably use @rene's user script introduced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250762/how-can-i-make-stack-overflow-make-a-sound-when-a-new-question-appears).

Comment: Related: [iPhone push notifications - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394972/iphone-push-notifications)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Stack Exchange APK since you use Android:
https://archive.org/details/stack-exchange-apk

Comment: I just installed it. Could you ping me in a comment to verify that it works?

Comment: @user000001 does it work?

Comment: It's strange, the notification appeared in the app when I opened it, but I got no notification in the android notification area and no sound from the phone.

Comment: @user000001 interesting, maybe needs some permissions, or perhaps in the application's settings?

Comment: They are enabled, maybe I opened the app too soon, I'll close the app and all SE browser windows, and see if I get any notifications while there is no active session.

Comment: @user000001 sounds good, maybe a bit of lag indeed

Comment: Thanks, I confirm that I got an inbox notification on the phone for a new comment that was posted for me.

Comment: @user000001 great, nice to hear!