# Is there a Stack Exchange WebSocket action for multiple tags?

Tags: support, tags, api, web-sockets

I'm developing an app to show all new questions for any tags that user is watching in realtime. So instead of using the REST API, I want to use the WebSocket at: `wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com`.

I'm able to observe for any tag with this action:
`<siteid>-questions-newest-tag-<tagname>`

And (looks like) I can observe as many as I need without limit. But when I send multiple actions for multiple tags, and **IF** a question has multiple tags of my choice together, The server respond me multiple times for a single question. For example `javascript` and `jquery`

My current solution is to keep the **id** of the responds and remove duplicates locally.

So **THE QUESTION IS**: Is there a built in way to remove duplicates? Like a unique action to get multiple tags or etc. Just like the original site itself.

-

Pseudo action desired *just for more clarification*:

`<siteid>-questions-newest-any-tags-<tagname>;<tagname>;<tagname>` // any

`<siteid>-questions-newest-all-tags-<tagname>;<tagname>;<tagname>` // all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such way. The [unofficial documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218355/295232) doesn't list such a method, and if you check which websockets are active on a page showing the [search results for [tag X] or [tag Y]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+or+feature-request) you'll see it subscribes to two separate tag feed websockets:

[image]

The way you describe is also the way I do it for a system which notifies me of potentially interesting questions across the network.

Comment: I hope there is a little trick or hidden documentation. I leave it open to see what others have to say.

Comment: by the way, what is that `|Questions/ListByTag|295239|6085540|71887|meta.stackexchange.com|1562672333|`? can you explain it a bit please?

Comment: `|type of page I'm on|user ID on site|my network ID|reputation|domain|current Unix timestamp|`