# Reputation display in top bar when accepting an answer in responsive design

Tags: support, bug, design, top-bar, responsive-design

There is a minor display issue in the desktop and mobile web view with the responsiveness is enabled.

When the responsiveness is enabled, usually we didn't see the reputation in the top bar. But if you are accepting an answer, when the +2 reputation added to the achievements icon, the reputation is also displaying in the top bar.

**Top bar in default view:**

> [image: default view]

**Top bar when accept an answer:**

> [image: when accept an answer]

It seems not a feature, may be a bug in the code.
Does the reputation display in the top bar is intentionally or a bug?

Comment: It started doing that ~3 weeks ago. Feature or Bug, it's up to you. The reputation is supposed to be displayed continuously (if the CSS thinks your screen is wide enough, and suppressed if it's not), so sometimes *working* is a Bug.

Answer (score 1):

The reputation update in the top bar is 'powered' by the same [websocket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218355/295232) on all pages. No matter where you are, you will always receive the same updates. It *might* take a few seconds for the +2 to register, so if you navigate away from the page too soon, you'll miss it. But AFAIK this has always been the case and is definitely [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).