# How can I get notified only for questions that belong to the intersection of two tags?

Tags: support, tags, notifications, tag-filters

I always have a Chrome tab open to watch only the questions that are tagged with [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase) **AND** [android](/questions/tagged/android). This is the URL:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase+android

The filtering mechanism works fine, as I'm able to see only the intersection of the tags. However, if a new question tagged with [android](/questions/tagged/android) is added, I get this:

[image: "1 question with new activity" notification]

If I refresh the page, no new question is present. If I check:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android

Indeed the new question belongs to the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag. How can I get notified only for [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase) **AND** [android](/questions/tagged/android)? As now I'm notified for a some kind of **OR**.

Comment: Already reported: [“X questions with new activity” showing incorrect information in windows with multiple tag filters](/q/343767/289905).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

The technology behind the notifications is Web Sockets, and there's a [list of available endpoints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218355/295232):

> - `<siteid>-questions-active-tag-<tagname>`: Active for a specific tag

There is no endpoint for the intersection of two tags. The [firebase]+[android] page connects to two websockets; one for each tag. It *would* be nice if the page detects that the [android]-only question does not pass your filter and hence not show the '1 question with new activity' notification.

Comment: Thank you. In this case, I have to refresh the page several times, until I get a question that belongs to the intersection of the tags.